# Laravel Notification model binding

Tags: laravel, notifications

I have a question.

How can I bind a model Notification class like Route Model Binding?

I want this;

When I give an integer value on class inside Notification class,
then the class should give me model,

Like this;

**ExampleController.php**

```
function show($id) {
    Notification::send(auth()->user(),new TestNotification($id));
}
```

**TestNotification.php**

```
public User $user;
public function __construct(User $user) {
  $this->user = $user;
}
```

Comment: there is no mechanism to do that directly especially since you are creating the notification object yourself

Comment: Can't we add it ourselves using AppServiceProvider?

Comment: You can simply code this into your `TestNotification` class, like `__construct($user) { $this->user = $user instanceof User ? $user : User::findOrFail($user); }` (or similar, i.e. maybe with a `try / catch` or additional logic for handling non-numeric IDs, etc.)

Comment: Maybe can i use it but wouldn't it be nice to have something like this?

Comment: Well, imagine that you delay the notification to the next day but for some reason the user is deleted right after you queue the notification. When the notification is processed, it will try to fetch a non-existent user, therefore you will face a 404. That's why I assume that you can only queue your notification with the whole model AKA $notifiable by doing `new TestNotification(User::firstOrFail($id))`